# Convert row-column-value data to an array - numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have data in long format that stores the row#, column# and value as shown below:

```
ROW  COLUMN   VALUE
  1       1       1
  1       3       3
  2       1       1
  2       2       2
  3       1       1
  3       2       2
  3       3       3
```

Please note that the certain ROW, COLUMN combinations are missing (for instance there is no value for ROW = 1 and COLUMN = 2). I would like to convert this into a 3 x 3 array like so. The missing row column combination gets filled in by 0:

```
   1    0   3
   1    2   0
   1    2   3
```

My initial approach to this problem was to declare an empty 3 x 3 array, read in the three columns as 1d arrays and loop over rows and columns and update the array based on the value array. For small dimensional cases this seems doable, but for higher dimensions this does not seem to be the "Pythonic" way to do it. Has this problem been tackled in some canned function in `numpy` package? I looked into `reshape` - but that assumes no missing values.

Comment: what is missing from row 1 column 2?

Comment: In array terms the value information for index (i,j) or (1,2) is missing from the data in long format. Edited question to show - does that clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the row, column and values in numpy arrays, you can do something like the following.  (Note that I've taken the more Pythonic approach of putting the 0-based indices in `row` and `col`).

Here's the data, in one-dimensonal arrays:

```
In [13]: row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

In [14]: col = np.array([0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2])

In [15]: values = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
```

Create a two-dimensional array to hold the values.  I use the maxima from `row` and `col` to figure out how big the array should be.  You might use some other values if `row` and `col` don't necessarily include values in the last row or column.

```
In [16]: a = np.zeros((row.max()+1, col.max()+1), dtype=values.dtype)
```

Now fill in the values with this assignment

```
In [17]: a[row, col] = values
```

*Et voilà*:

```
In [18]: a
Out[18]: 
array([[11,  0, 12],
       [13, 14,  0],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

---

Your example is a 3x3 array, but if you will actually have much larger arrays and not a lot of entries, you might consider using a [scipy sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).  For example, here's how you can create a "COO" matrix from the same data as above, using the [`coo_matrix` class](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html):

```
In [25]: from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

In [26]: c = coo_matrix((values, (row, col)), shape=(row.max()+1, col.max()+1))

In [27]: c
Out[27]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [28]: c.A
Out[28]: 
array([[11,  0, 12],
       [13, 14,  0],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```